# How to submit a YARN job using APPLICATION ID

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I would like to know if there is any possibility provided by the YARN CLI to re-submit a YARN application by using APPLICATION_ID which is generated from the previous execution.

Example:

```
/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0/bin/spark-submit --num-executors 5 --executor-memory 2G --executor-cores 2  --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --files /opt/mapr/hive/hive-2.1/conf/hive-site.xml --class com.cisco.sdp.cdx.processing.DenormScheduler JSONDenormJob-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

When i submit the above job YARN creates an APPLICATION_ID (Ex: application_1522909218432_0485). Is there a way to resubmit the job same job using the APPLICATION_ID either from the commandline or from the JAVA API.

like `yarn application -submit <APPLICATION_ID>`. From the help i could see there is an option  `-movetoqueue <Application ID>`. I do not see any option to resubmit. Just trying to explore and understand what could be the reason for not providing the option to resubmit a job.

Answer (score 0):

YARN does not have this ability from API perspective. Application id is generated as response to [createApplication](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/client/api/YarnClient.html#createApplication()) call, which does not receive any arguments.